# Do tinymce still prevent the upload .svg file via its editor?

Tags: svg, file-upload, tinymce-5

On tinymce v5.10, I want to allow the upload on .svg type of image and am not able to do it. I wanted to know if there is a possibility to allow .svg file to be uploaded through drag and drop or upload dialog.

Answer (score 0):

SVG uploads are not supported by default because they are a **security risk**. A user could insert malicious code into an SVG and upload it to your server. However, it is possible to allow them if you use `image_file_types` in your `tinymce.init`:

```
tinymce.init({
  // ...
  images_file_types: 'svg,jpeg,jpg,jpe,jfi,jif,jfif,png,gif,bmp,webp'
});
```

Use at your own risk, and **SVGs should be sanitized on the server-side to avoid XSS attacks.**

image_file_types docs: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_file_types